# AppCompat Error onCreate()

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I just imported my project which worked fine from Eclipse to Android Studio v1.2.11 and now the project is no longer working with the following error which make the app crashes at onCreate() method:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.
```

I have updated updated my app to the latest v7 library, i.e. 22.1.1. below is my gradle.build dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0') {
    force = true
}
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0') {
    force = true
}
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.3.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.2'
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'bolts'
}
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
compile project(':PullToRefreshListView')
compile project(':CircularImageView')
compile project(':CountryPicker')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1'
}

configurations {
// to avoid double inclusion of support libraries
all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

NB: I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light in my styles which I believe supports ActionBar. What I want to achieve is the Nav. drawer but the app doesn't go past the onCreate(). Any help with this exception will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having similar issue, I was able to solve this and thought I should share with others. The error was due to my configuration as I was excluding the android.support in my project. Once I commented it, it just vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class dependency is in your application specific build.gradle file, not your global build.gradle file.

[image: Location of application specific build.gradle file]